# Group by clause in Entity Framework or Micro ORM using lambda

Tags: entity-framework, sql-server-2008, micro-orm

How to use following query by using Lambda Expression (Entity Framework or Micro ORM)?

```
    SELECT a.RestaurantID
        ,MAX(a.EventDate) LastPeriodCloseDate
    FROM (
        SELECT RestaurantID
            ,EventType
            ,EventDate
        FROM SystemCalendar
        WHERE EventType = 'P'
       ) a
   GROUP BY RestaurantID
   HAVING MAX(a.EventDate) BETWEEN '2014-10-31'
         AND '2015-03-31'
```

Comment: Please add your C# code. It's not clear where exactly you stuck and what problem you have

Comment: I want to get the same output of above query using C# lambda expression instead of using tsql. Unable to handle both group by and having clause together using lambda for entity framework.

Comment: I am new in this area and trying to use something like following. Unable to put having clause criteria...            var list = _db.SystemCalendars
                    .Where(e => e.EventType == "P")
                    .GroupBy(r => r.RestaurantID)
                    .Select(s => new
                     {
                         RestaurantID = s.FirstOrDefault().RestaurantID
                        ,LastPeriodCloseDate = s.Count()
                     });

Answer (score 0):

Your inner select isn't necessary. You can just do this:

```
DateTime start = new DateTime(2014, 10, 31);
DateTime end = new DateTime(2015, 3, 31);

var query = _db.SystemCalendar
               .Where(x => x.EventType == "P")
               .GroupBy(x => x.RestaurantID, 
                        x => new 
                        { 
                          RestaurantID = x.Key, 
                          LastPeriodCloseDate = x.Max(y => y.EventDate) 
                        })
               .Where(x => x.LastPeriodCloseDate >= start && 
                           x.LastPeriodCloseDate < end);
```